# network applications in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, network-programming

I want to build an application to connect to a network server and share the datas with it. Could any one please inform me, any sample applications or tutorials to help me in this path. Thank you.

Comment: What kind of network server is that?

Comment: I want to connect to the web and access the datas stored in that web server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read the documentation for [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003755) and [related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nsurlconnection?sort=votes) here on Stack Overflow. There’s also a lot of [interesting source code on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=nsurlconnection).

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSocketPort_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Read it, it will help you.

Comment: Why start with sockets? I think that some higher-level interface like `NSURLConnection` would be better.

Answer (score -1):

IU think you need to study about externalAccessories framework . to add external devices through iphone

Comment: He doesn’t want to connect the server directly to the machine, he just wants to access some data over HTTP. Or at least that’s the way I read the question.